# string in source file line replace to matched string in destination file

Tags: linux, text-processing

destination file content

```
shivps 256146 54645 46561431
kaspsa 212142 21244 21144664
```

source file content

```
shivps 111111 22222 33333333
kaspsa 222222 11111 44444444
```

how to replace for same name line with different data from source file to destination file

Comment: Not sure what you mean, as with your examples you could just do `cp source destination`. But I guess you have lines not matching in your files? maybe you could point that out and give some example lines that are different. Please add your desired output.

Comment: Where do these numberic strings in the destination file come from? Is this the desired content or the original content?

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and clearly state what files with what contents you have before executing a command/script to be defined and what file and contents you want to get. You can use example file names, e.g. I have file `foo` containing `some contents`and file `bar` containing `other contents` and want the file `foo` to be changed to `again other contents` and the file `bar` to be unchanged. Or I want to create a new file `baz` containing `whatever you want`. Explain if the values in the output are fixed or depend on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Using a while read loop will just output the result to stdout and not edit the file in-place.

Contents of source.txt

```
shivps 111111 22222 33333333 Iam_from_source.txt
Iam_from_source-source-source
kaspsa 222222 11111 44444444 Iam_from_source.txt
Iam_from_source-source-source
```

Contents of destination.txt

```
shivps 256146 54645 46561431 Iam_from_destination.txt
Iam_from_destination-destination
kaspsa 212142 21244 21144664 Iam_from_destination.txt
Iam_from_destination-destination
```

The script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source=$1
destination=$2

while IFS= read -r lines_from_source <&3; do
   IFS= read -r lines_from_destination
   if [[ ${lines_from_source%% *} == ${lines_from_destination%% *} ]]; then
     printf '%s\n' "${lines_from_source//$lines_from_destination}"
   else
     printf '%s\n' "$lines_from_destination"
   fi
done 3<"$source" < "$destination"
```

Run script.

```
./script source.txt destination.txt
```

Output

```
shivps 111111 22222 33333333 Iam_from_source.txt
Iam_from_destination-destination
kaspsa 222222 11111 44444444 Iam_from_source.txt
Iam_from_destination-destination
```

- It works on the sample data you provided, might fail if you have more pattern to match.
- For large data/files it will be very slow.